# IBM MQ PCFMessage Agent for channel status

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to retrieve the channel status of a remote Queue Manager using PCFMessageAgent. While I am trying to create the instance of it I am getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/ibm/mq/internal/MQCommonServices    at
com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.getJmqiEnv(PCFAgent.java:124)   at
com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.<init>(PCFAgent.java:132)   at
com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.<init>(PCFAgent.java:146)   at
com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFMessageAgent.<init>(PCFMessageAgent.java:126)     at
com.sample.model.Test2.main(Test2.java:77) Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     ... 5 more
```

For the reference I am putting the code here.

```
    MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;           
    MQEnvironment.port  = port;            
    MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
    MQQueueManager qMgr=null;
    PCFMessageAgent agent =null;
         try {
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
            agent = new PCFMessageAgent (qMgr);
            mes= new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS);
            mes.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "*");
            mes.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_TYPE, CMQXC.MQCHT_ALL);
            mes.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_ATTRS,
                              new int []
                              {
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_SUBSTATE,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_MSGS,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_LAST_MSG_DATE,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_LAST_MSG_TIME,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_START_DATE,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_START_TIME,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_BYTES_SENT,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_BYTES_RECEIVED,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_BUFFERS_SENT,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_BUFFERS_RECEIVED,
                                 CMQCFC.MQIACH_MCA_STATUS,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_MCA_JOB_NAME,
                                 CMQCFC.MQCACH_MCA_USER_ID
                              } );
                  res = agent.send(mes);
                  }
                  catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

I have included

1. com.ibm.mq.jar
2. com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
3. com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
4. com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
5. com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
6. com.ibm.mqjms.jar
7. connector.jar
8. dhbcore.jar
9. fscontext.jar
10. providerutil.jar

Moreover, I have tried to create the instance using other constructors of PCFMessageAgent. It is throwing same exception every time. Note: I am able to connect to queue manager and do operations like get or put messages to the queues etc.

Can anyone tell me what I might have missed here?
Has anyone else has faced the same problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the commonservices.jar is available at runtime?  I believe it compiles fine but throws NoClassDefFoundError at runtime.